# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(' in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<img src="../image/cross_bt.png" width="20px" style="cursor:pointer;position: absolute;top: -10px;right: -10px;width: 30px;" onClick="$.(.dtl_tr_<?php echo$gid?>).hide();$.(.dtl_td_<?php echo$gid?>).html('');">
```

when ever I click on the image it shows ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('***.

How I can solve this?

Comment: Create jQuery Selector properly i.e.  `$('.dtl_tr_<?php echo$gid?>').hide();;$('.dtl_td_<?php echo$gid?>').html('');"`

Comment: Incorrect selector syntax.